# Not able to insert data in the database from a form in php

Tags: php

I am not able to insert data into my data, i dont know what the problem is. Here is the code:

mysql_select_db("mitestore", $con); */
if ((isset($_POST['product_name'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['product_name'])) > 0)) {
    $product_name = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['product_name']));
    $sql="INSERT INTO sell (product_name) VALUE ('$_POST[product_name]')";
} else {$product_name = 'Please enter the product name.';}
if ((isset($_POST[''])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['how_old'])) > 0)) {
    $how_old = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['how_old']));
    $sql="INSERT INTO sell (how_old) VALUE ('$_POST[how_old]')";
} else {$how_old = 'Please enter how old your product is';}
if ((isset($_POST['which_block'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['which_block'])) > 0)) {
    $which_block = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['which_block']));
    $sql="INSERT INTO sell (which_block) VALUE ('$_POST[which_block]')";
} else {$which_block = 'Please enter which block are you from';}
if ((isset($_POST['room_no'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['room_no'])) > 0)) {
    $room_no = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['room_no']));
    $sql="INSERT INTO sell (room_no) VALUE ('$_POST[room_no]')";
} else {$room_no = 'Please enter the room no:';}
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "Success!";

mysql_close($con)
?>

Initially i had this code and it worked for me.

mysql_select_db("database", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO sell ( product_name, how_old , selling_price, negotiable, which_block, room_no)
VALUES
('$_POST[product_name]','$_POST[how_old]','$_POST[selling_price]','$_POST[negotiable]','$_POST[which_block]','$_POST[room_no]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "Your product is added.";
mysql_close($con)
?>

But i don't know how to validate each field individually.

Comment: Two things scream at me here. 1. SQL injection vulnerability. 2. `root` level SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Apart from the injection problems which SHOULD be your first priority, as it is its better it does not work ;), but could you check error log for apache for some errors to guide us.

Comment: The way you seem to be inserting rows for each column value shows that you don't understand relational databases in the first place. You need to find a good book.

Comment: @Dan Grossman, That should be an answer I believe :)

Comment: Need...more...info. What do you experience? Any error messages? What's your table structure? Scratch our backs so we can scratch yours.

Comment: @Dan: This is exactly what I thought when I looked at the code. @Prashant: Please learn how to properly protect your queries and, in general, study proper code flow. A good starting place would be mysql_real_escape_string() and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental problem: You don't understand how relational databases work.

You want to store a product name, block number, room number, etc. for some product in a store.

An `INSERT` query creates a row in a table. You need to put all those values into one row, so you need to put them all in one `INSERT` query.

```
INSERT INTO sell (product_name, how_old, which_block, room_no) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

You should build this one query then execute it.

If your code worked, what it would create is a table where each row has one value in each column, with no way to know which of them correspond to the same product.

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code into my server and made a minor modification, but basically the same code and it worked fine for me. You do have a lingering piece of comment "*/" on line 8.

Also, I would advise using the MDB2 library so you can do stored procedures... to project from injections.

MDB2 would look something likethis:

```
    $db=dbConnect();
    $q = "INSERT INTO mytable (year,name,email) VALUE (?,?,?)"; 
    $prep = $this->db->prepare($q, array('integer','text','text'));
    $res = $prep->execute(array($year,$name,$email));
```